# How to know the end of FTP Welcome message

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, inputstream

My problem is that I'm creating a FTP client, and so far its working flawlessly besides one minor detail, that keeps bugging me.
I need to know how many lines the FTP welcome message spans over... And this cannot be acceptable!

```
    private Socket connection;
    private PrintWriter outStream;
    private Scanner inStream;

public void InitiateConnection() throws IOException 
{
    log.Info(this, "Initiating connection to host: " + host + ":" + port);
    connection = new Socket(host, port);
    log.Info(this, "Connection initiated.");
    outStream = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);
    inStream = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
    Listen();
    Listen();    
    Listen();
}

public String Listen() throws IOException
{
    if(connection == null)
        throw new IOException("Connection not initiated yet");
    String response = inStream.nextLine();
    log.Info(this, "Response: " + response);
    return response;
}
```

This is the simple setup, I have left out all other code, as it doesn't have anything to do with my problem.

I have tried multiple things to try to achieve this.
Failed Solution 1:

```
String response = "";
while(response != null)
    Listen();
```

Failed Solution 2:

```
while(connection.getInputStream().available > 0)
    Listen();
```

And countless others... But either it doesn't work, or the methods block and wait for new input. I have even tried with a timeout, but that doesn't work flawlessly either, its not a proper solution to this problem...

I need to be able to get the entire welcome message from the FTP server, without knowing the amount of lines...
So I can both get this:

```
Response:   220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.39 beta
Response:   220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
Response:   220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
```

And this:

```
Response:   220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.40 beta
Response:   220 Welcome to Andrés FTP Server
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a close look at the messages, you see that all but the last lines have a `-` behind the status code. The last line has a , however, indicating, well, the last line.

You can read that in [RFC 959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html), section 4.2:

> Thus the format for multi-line replies is that the first line
>   will begin with the exact required reply code, followed
>   immediately by a Hyphen, "-" (also known as Minus), followed by
>   text.  The last line will begin with the same code, followed
>   immediately by Space , optionally some text, and the Telnet
>   end-of-line code.

There is nothing said about the 2nd to second-last line, but it is logical that they have the same format as the 1st one.

---

Update: The FTP protocol seems to be badly documented, but I found another reference stating the same as me above:

The [TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_FTPRepliesReplyCodeFormatandImportantReplyCodes-5.htm) mentions that

> It is possible for a reply to contain more than one line of text. In this case, each line starts with the reply code, and all lines but the last have a hyphen between the reply code and the reply text, to indicate that the reply continues. The last line has a space between the reply code and reply text, just like a single-line reply. This facility is often used to provide additional response information after a user logs in, via the 230 reply code.

Comment: This is the *multiline* reply format. From the same section: "An FTP reply consists of a three digit number (transmitted as three alphanumeric characters) followed by some text." It is not clear from the spec but if you startup FileZilla you will see that the only ML response in the connect procedure is the 211 response on FEAT command.

Comment: Although the TCP/IP Guide's example is compliant with RFC 959, its description of the requirement is not correct. [RFC 959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) section 4.2 includes an example of a multi-line reply. Only the first line **must** start with 3-digit number followed by a hyphen. After that, the only requirement is that the last line (and only the last line) must begin with the same 3-digit number from line 1 followed by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    do {            
        response.append(br.readLine());                                     
    }
    while (br.ready());
```

Whereas the [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)'s [ready()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready%28%29) method:

> Tells whether this stream is ready to be read. A buffered character stream is ready if the buffer is not empty, or if the underlying character stream is ready.
>   
> Returns:
>   True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise. Note that returning false does not guarantee that the next read will block.

It is actually a [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)'s  [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready%28%29).

UPDATE:

As glglgl pointed out there are two types of responses in FTP:

- "single line" response  (my term)
- multiline  response  (spec term)

As I said in comment, fire up FIlleZilla, connect and observe the log (preferably comparing the commands in output with spec defintion) and you will see why the "single line" is quoted.

On some FTP server implementations the above code may work, but it will surley not work on all implementations, since it does not implement the client part of the protocol correctly. This is the updated version:

```
String response;
List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();  
boolean isMultilineStart = false, isMultilineEnd = false;
String mlCode = null;
do {            
   responseList.add(br.readLine());                           
   if (!isMultilineStart) {
        isMultilineStart = responseList.get(responseList.size()-1).matches("\\d\\d\\d-.*");                
        mlCode = responseList.get(responseList.size()-1).substring(0,3);
   }
   else {
       isMultilineEnd = responseList.get(responseList.size()-1).startsWith(mlCode+" ");
   }
}
while (br.ready() || (isMultilineStart && !isMultilineEnd));   
response = Arrays.deepToString(responseList.toArray());
```

Comment: No I haven't, but I'm definetely going to try it out.

Comment: But you don't know if the server has really finished, or if a packet is under the way, but has not yet arrived. Better rely to the facilities provided by the protocol.

Comment: @glglgl "My problem is that I'm creating a FTP client..." it looks like he's implementing the client side of the protocol.

Comment: Of course. But the client has to know whe nthe server has finished, and the FTP protocol exactly defines when this is the case.

Comment: @glglgl Agreed. There are very few correct uses of available() and ready(), and this isn't one of them. -1.