# How to read multiline response from FTP server?

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, unix-socket

I am writing FTP client program in C. I am use blocking socket. I have put `recv ()` in while loop and I break it when last two received characters are `\r\n`. I am able to run it on some servers but it doesn't read whole message on some servers like `ftp.secyt.gov.ar`.

I think the problem is because of the messages from server which contains characters `\r` `\n` together.

How should I deal with such case?

After sending the user name and password to server at `ftp.secyt.gov.ar`, I want to print the message received from server.

```c
password = getpass("Password: ");
sprintf(pass, "PASS %s\r\n",password);

send(sockfd, pass, strlen(pass), 0);

while((no_of_bytes = recv(sockfd, message_from_server, MAXSZ, 0)) > 0)
{
    message_from_server[no_of_bytes] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", message_from_server);

    if (message_from_server[no_of_bytes-2] == '\r' &&
        message_from_server[no_of_bytes-1] == '\n')
        break;
}
```

Server sends this message:

```
230-=====================================================================

    BIENVENIDOS AL SERVIDOR FTP DE LA MINCyT   
             ----------------------------------------

Usuario anonymous, desde la maquina ::ffff:116.203.73.60, gracias por
utilizar el FTP del Ministerio de Ciencia, Tecnologia e
Innovacion Productiva.

Para sugerencias, consultas o informacin adicional nuestros correos 
electrnicos son:
                     webmaster@mincyt.gov.ar

=========================================================================
230 User anonymous logged in.
```

But it is printing only:

```
230-=====================================================================
```

Comment: 1) Show us your code! 2) *it doesn't read whole message on some servers*: So *what* does it read? 3) *contains characters '\r' '\n' together*: What does that mean?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please see to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code reads a line (a string terminated by `\r\n`) from the server.

But an FTP response can be multi-line, according to the FTP specification.

See the [RFC 959, section 4.2 FTP Replies](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959#page-36):

> Thus the format for multi-line replies is that the first line
> will begin with the exact required reply code, followed
> immediately by a Hyphen, "-" (also known as Minus), followed by
> text.  The last line will begin with the same code, followed
> immediately by Space , optionally some text, and the Telnet
> end-of-line code.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>  123-First line  
>  Second line  
>    234 A line beginning with numbers  
>  123 The last line
> ```
>
> The user-process then simply needs to search for the second
> occurrence of the same reply code, followed by  (Space), at
> the beginning of a line, and ignore all intermediary lines.  If
> an intermediary line begins with a 3-digit number, the Server
> must pad the front  to avoid confusion.

---

See also [How to know the end of FTP Welcome message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13082538/850848).